# Reading value from MySql table using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm having trouble trying to read from a MySQL databse using VB.NET, the error message I get is "ArgumentExcpetion was unhandled"

Also, the reading should return 'F', since this is the value allocated on that specific place on the table.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim query As String = "SELECT DO FROM klein WHERE COMMAND='DELETE'"
        Dim connStr As String = "server=" & TextBox1.Text & ";" _
            & "user id=" & TextBox2.Text & ";" _
            & "password=" & TextBox3.Text & ";" _
            & "database=hidro201_liberato"
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            TextBox4.Text = (reader.GetChar(1))   '<- **problem is here**
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one column in your query and the index of the column should be zero

```
TextBox4.Text = (reader.GetChar(0))
```

[This is for SqlServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getchar.aspx) but the rules are the same for a MySqlDataReader

Comment: I'm having another problem, I want to read an entry on the database and update is as follows, although it's not updating and it's also not giving any kind of error

Comment: sorry but I can't help without seeing the code that tries the update

Answer (score 1):

The field index is zero based.

```
TextBox4.Text = (reader.GetChar(0))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getchar.aspx

Parameter i: "The zero-based column ordinal."

Answer (score 0):

TextBox4.Text = (reader.GetChar("Name of column to get the value"))
All the best